# Eliminate Duplicate records from Oracle Array of Object

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I do have following object and array declared in Oracle :

```
create or replace
TYPE TestObj as
OBJECT (parent_key varchar2(20), child_key varchar2(20),
```

dt date, other1 varchar2(20), other2 varchar2(20));
and

```
create or replace 
    TYPE TestArray as TABLE OF TestObj;
```

Now in one of my SP I am getting following type as an Input :

```
IN_TestArray IN TestArray
```

Now in this array I am getting following set of data which includes few duplicates too :

```
Id  Parent_key    Child_Key   dt         other1     other2
===========================================================
1    AT              AA      2016-06-22    test1       test2
2    AT              A0      2016-06-22    test3       test4
3    BT              BA      2016-06-22    test5       test6
4    AT              AA      2016-06-22    test1       test2
5    AT              AA      2016-06-21    test21      test22
6    CT              CA      2016-06-22    test23      test24
7    AT              AA      2016-06-22    test31      test32
```

Here I want to eliminate duplicate records from array with combination of **parent_key, child_key, and dt.**

So the updated array should have only following rows after process :

```
(any one from 1, 4, 7)
2
3
5
6
```

Any help would be appreciated.....

Comment: What is the logic for keeping 1 and discarding 4 and 7 - how do you decide which other1/other2 values you want to keep? Are you trying to stop the duplicates going into your array, trying to remove them once they are there, or ignore them when using the values? Seeing how your SP uses the array might be useful. (You've left out part of the declaration of TestArray - is it `table of TestObj`?)

Comment: Updated the question, anyone from 1 or 4 or 7 will work for me... and yes its TABLE of TestObj..

Comment: Why do you keep adding and removing those two dots, form a line which shouldn't really be there anyway? Are you just trying to artificially bump your question repeatedly on to the front page?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`SET()` collection function](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/functions163.htm#SQLRF06308) to get rid of exact duplicates.

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TYPE TestObj AS OBJECT (
  parent_key varchar2(20),
  child_key  varchar2(20),
  dt         date,
  other1     varchar2(20),
  other2     varchar2(20)
);
/

CREATE TYPE TestArray AS TABLE OF TestObj;
/
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE(
         SET(
          TestArray(
            TestObj( 'AT', 'AA', DATE '2016-06-22', 'test1', 'test2' ),
            TestObj( 'AT', 'AA', DATE '2016-06-22', 'test1', 'test2' )
          )
         )
       );
```

**Output**:

```
PARENT_KEY   CHILD_KEY    DT                  OTHER1       OTHER2
------------ ------------ ------------------- ------------ ------------
AT           AA           2016-06-22 00:00:00 test1        test2
```

If you want to get duplicates only on a subset of the rows then you can use:

```
SELECT TestObj(
         parent_key,
         child_key,
         dt,
         MIN( other1 ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY ROWNUM ),
         MIN( other2 ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY ROWNUM )
       )
BULK COLLECT INTO array_unique
FROM   TABLE( array_with_dups )
GROUP BY parent_key, child_key, dt;
```

Like this:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
  array_with_dups TestArray
       := TestArray(
            TestObj( 'AT', 'AA', DATE '2016-06-22', 'test1', 'test2' ),
            TestObj( 'AT', 'AA', DATE '2016-06-22', 'test1', 'test2' ),
            TestObj( 'AT', 'AA', DATE '2016-06-22', 'test31', 'test32' )
          );
  array_unique TestArray;
BEGIN
  SELECT TestObj(
           parent_key,
           child_key,
           dt,
           MIN( other1 ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY ROWNUM ),
           MIN( other2 ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY ROWNUM )
         )
  BULK COLLECT INTO array_unique
  FROM   TABLE( array_with_dups )
  GROUP BY parent_key, child_key, dt;

  FOR i IN 1 .. array_unique.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
      array_unique(i).parent_key
      || ', ' || array_unique(i).child_key
      || ', ' || array_unique(i).dt
      || ', ' || array_unique(i).other1
      || ', ' || array_unique(i).other2
    );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

**Output**:

```
AT, AA, 2016-06-22 00:00:00, test1, test2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [delete from a collection](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/composites.htm#LNPLS99961), but you need to identify the index value to use. This is a bit messy but should work:

```
  for r in (
    select i from (
      select t.*, rownum as i,
        row_number() over (partition by parent_key, child_key, dt
          order by other1, other2) as key_rn
      from table(in_testarray) t
      )
    where key_rn > 1
  )
  loop
    in_testarray.delete(r.i);
  end loop;
```

Demo:

```
declare
 in_testarray testarray;
begin
  select *
  bulk collect into in_testarray
  from (
    select testobj('AT', 'AA', date '2016-06-22', 'test1', 'test2') from dual
    union all select testobj('AT', 'A0', date '2016-06-22', 'test3', 'test4') from dual
    union all select testobj('BT', 'BA', date '2016-06-22', 'test5', 'test6') from dual
    union all select testobj('AT', 'AA', date '2016-06-22', 'test1', 'test2') from dual
    union all select testobj('AT', 'AA', date '2016-06-21', 'test21', 'test22') from dual
    union all select testobj('CT', 'CA', date '2016-06-22', 'test23', 'test24') from dual
    union all select testobj('AT', 'AA', date '2016-06-22', 'test31', 'test32') from dual
  );

  for r in (
    select i from (
      select t.*, rownum as i,
        row_number() over (partition by parent_key, child_key, dt
          order by other1, other2) as key_rn
      from table(in_testarray) t
      )
    where key_rn > 1
  )
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line('deleting ' || r.i);
    in_testarray.delete(r.i);
  end loop;

  for i in in_testarray.first..in_testarray.last loop
    if in_testarray.exists(i) then
      dbms_output.put_line(i ||': '|| in_testarray(i).parent_key ||':'|| in_testarray(i).child_key
        ||':'|| in_testarray(i).dt ||':'|| in_testarray(i).other1 ||':'|| in_testarray(i).other2);
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

The collection ends up with five members:

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

deleting 4
deleting 7
1: AT:AA:2016-06-22:test1:test2
2: AT:A0:2016-06-22:test3:test4
3: BT:BA:2016-06-22:test5:test6
5: AT:AA:2016-06-21:test21:test22
6: CT:CA:2016-06-22:test23:test24
```

But it may not be a good idea to directly modify a passed-in array (and it may not be allowed for an IN parameter anyway), so you should probably modify a copy of the original array.

Alternatively you could make a copy of the collection that leaves out the duplicates; if you declare say `my_testarray` of the same type:

```
  select testobj(parent_key, child_key, dt, other1, other2)
  bulk collect into my_testarray
  from (
    select t.*,
      row_number() over (partition by parent_key, child_key, dt
        order by other1, other2) as key_rn
    from table(in_testarray) t
  )
  where key_rn = 1;
```

and then use that collection instead of your original one.

Quick demo:

```
declare
 in_testarray testarray;
 my_testarray testarray;
begin
  select *
  bulk collect into in_testarray
  from (
    select testobj('AT', 'AA', date '2016-06-22', 'test1', 'test2') from dual
    union all select testobj('AT', 'A0', date '2016-06-22', 'test3', 'test4') from dual
    union all select testobj('BT', 'BA', date '2016-06-22', 'test5', 'test6') from dual
    union all select testobj('AT', 'AA', date '2016-06-22', 'test1', 'test2') from dual
    union all select testobj('AT', 'AA', date '2016-06-21', 'test21', 'test22') from dual
    union all select testobj('CT', 'CA', date '2016-06-22', 'test23', 'test24') from dual
    union all select testobj('AT', 'AA', date '2016-06-22', 'test31', 'test32') from dual
  );

  select testobj(parent_key, child_key, dt, other1, other2)
  bulk collect into my_testarray
  from (
    select t.*,
      row_number() over (partition by parent_key, child_key, dt
        order by other1, other2) as key_rn
    from table(in_testarray) t
  )
  where key_rn = 1;

  for i in my_testarray.first..my_testarray.last loop
    dbms_output.put_line(i ||': '|| my_testarray(i).parent_key ||':'|| my_testarray(i).child_key
      ||':'|| my_testarray(i).dt ||':'|| my_testarray(i).other1 ||':'|| my_testarray(i).other2);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

which gets the same output, but the collection isn't sparse now:

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

1: AT:A0:2016-06-22:test3:test4
2: AT:AA:2016-06-21:test21:test22
3: AT:AA:2016-06-22:test1:test2
4: BT:BA:2016-06-22:test5:test6
5: CT:CA:2016-06-22:test23:test24
```

Or you can do something similar at the point you use the original collection, e.g. in a table collection expression.